# How to open terminal in split in vimrc with keybinding

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, terminal

I am trying to open a new terminal (size of 10) inside of neovim.  I use the command, `:split|resize20|term`. It works well, but I want to make a hotkey to do this in my init.vim

```
nnoremap <C-P> :split|resize20|term<CR>
```

For some reason, when I actually run it, I get an error saying, `parse error near >`. Sometimes, when I add spaces between the pipes in the above command, it runs split only, and gives a weird error.

How do I create keybindings for the above command?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The answer is probably in `:help map-bar`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you so much, I was able to find the solution by replacing each | with <Bar>

Comment: Not the best dupe-target, so if anyone has better suggestions, please suggest them.